# How to set title of DXRibbonWindow in its center

Tags: wpf, ribbon-control, dxribbonwindow

I'm using `DXRibbonwindow` like this:

```
<dxr:DXRibbonWindow  x:Class="MyNameSpace.MyRibbonWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:dxn="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/navbar"
    xmlns:dxb="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/bars"
    xmlns:dxd="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/docking"
    xmlns:dxlc="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/layoutcontrol"
    xmlns:dxr="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/ribbon"
    xmlns:dxmvvm="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/mvvm"
    SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowState="Maximized"
    Title="title">
    <Grid>
        ...
    </Grid>
</dxr:DXRibbonWindow>
```

[image]
I want the title to be in the middle of the window's titlebar, but it doesn't, how can i make it? I'm using DevExpress 14.2.5 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occured in version 14.5 of DEVExpress, I upgrade its version to the newest 17.1 then the problem has been solved, thanks for the DevExpress developer.

Answer (score 1):

Override default control template using `Visual Studio Blend` or like it's explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825030/how-to-extract-default-control-template-in-visual-studio)
I would recommend to use `Blend` see an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35008585/comparison-visual-studio-2015-and-blend-for-visual-studio) and [the difference blend and VS editors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35008585/comparison-visual-studio-2015-and-blend-for-visual-studio)