# What is the difference between Visual Studio and Blend for Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

Why did Microsoft develop Visual Studio and Blend for Visual Studio and yet Visual Studio itself is a complete tool?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparison Visual studio 2015 and Blend for Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35008585/comparison-visual-studio-2015-and-blend-for-visual-studio)

Answer (score 1):

Visual studio you code everything in the .xaml window in the solution, in blend it does the code for you and you just change the properties via the code or via the interface.

Comment: ... and yet Visual Studio used to have both options integrated, and now it seems it's removed. This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: maybe it doesn't but the answer falls in line with what stackoverflow allows. Asking "why" something is different isn't allowed because it's irrelevant and muddies search results. 
In any case, it's not removed.  Blend is a component of visual studio.  It just opens in a new window.